# Adding a text overlay on a featured image in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to display a list of projects (Custom post type). Just the title, tags, featured image and the permalink:

```
      <li>
        <div class="blog_item">
          <a class="full_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
          <div class="abs_bg"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
          <div class="blog_item_inner">
            <h3 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <h5><?php the_tags(' '); ?></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Very simple idea, when you hover over the image, the text appears and you can click anywhere on it and view the post.

Usually this would be done by using one anchor tag with the other elements inside it but for some reason that method just seems to create 2 permalinks and messes the whole thing up.

Another issue is i'm trying to make the image responsive. I'm using percentage width and heights but unless I make the parent **.blog_item** element a fixed height, I can't get the entire image to display.

I've created a test here - https://jsfiddle.net/w54htg7g/

Here's the CSS:

```
    .blog_item {
      position: relative;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .blog_item .abs_bg {
      display: block;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .blog_item .blog_item_inner {
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .7em;
    }
    .blog_item .full_link {
      z-index: 3;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .blog_item:hover {
      background: #000;
    }
    .blog_item:hover .abs_bg {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

And this is how I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `position` property of `.blog_item .blog_item_inner {}` to `position: absolute;` rather than `position:relative;`

This will absolutely position that content within the `.blog_item` element, because `.blog_item {}` is the parent element and has been positioned relatively.

You may need to further refine the CSS for `.blog_item .blog_item_inner {}`. However, this should be a step in the correct direction.

It is somewhat difficult to be exact and precise when there's no example to test like a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.ne) link, and only pieces of code are present.